# Java interface overriding a protected method

Tags: java, scala, interface, overriding, protected

So, there is a java interface:

```
public interface SomeJavaStuff {
   Object clone();
}
```

that overrides `clone` in `Object`, which is protected.
Some java api returns an instance of that interface, and I am trying to use it in scala:

```
val stuff: SomeJavaStuff = someApi()
stuff.clone
```

This causes an error:

```
  method clone in class Object cannot be accessed in SomeJavaStuff 
  Access to protected method clone not permitted because
  prefix type SomeJavaStuff does not conform to
  class ThisClass in package foowhere the access take place
```

This looks like a bug in scala compiler.
Right? The method is public in the interface, I should be able to access it.

Comment: Why would you want to use an interface for a method that is implemented in _Java_'s `Object`? _EVERY_ instance will have the `clone()` method defined surely? Incidentally, `clone()` will only work if the resulting class implements the marker trait `Cloneable` _and_ overrides `clone()`, typically, with a `public` method that calls `super.clone()`. I don't think you're overriding the function in the `SomeJavaStuff` interface.

Comment: @MikeAllen yes, that's the idea. The interface is `Cloneable` and redeclares `clone` as public to allow downstream code to access it. That's a more or less standard pattern in java, unfortunately. 
In any case, that's not my interface, and I am not overriding anything. I am using a java API, and need to clone the object to modify it. This is obviously the intent of the interface author, and should work according to java access rules (it does in fact work in java).

Comment: Are you saying that what you've called `SomeJavaStuff` is actually `Cloneable`? Because `Cloneable` does not redeclare `clone()` to be public.

Comment: `Cloneable` doesn't, but `SomeJavaStuff` does. It is beyond the point, whether the underlying object actually implements `Cloneable` or overrides `clone` to do something entirely different. The point is that `clone` is declared to be public. Why can I not call the method?

Comment: Can you post a reference to the actual API you're trying to use?

Comment: How is `someApi` creating an instance of `SomeJavaStuff` without overriding the public `clone()` method defined in `SomeJavaStuff`? I couldn't create write a `class Foo implements SomeJavaStuff` without declaring my own public version of `clone`. And when I did define a clone implementation it worked just fine from Scala.

Comment: @Samuel I have no idea how it is creating the instance. It probably, does override `clone`. I mean, I can find out how it is doing it, but the whole point of the interface is that I am not supposed to care about the concrete implementation. Right?

Comment: @MikeAllen here is the api:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-models/src/main/java/io/swagger/models/Model.java

Comment: What is the `someApi()` method that you get the instance from?

Comment: If it's `RefModel` that is being returned, it's interesting to note that it is doing a non-standard implementation of `clone()` that appears to add no value - the default `clone()` method does the same job, a shallow copy of the original object. In which case, this is an odd result.

Comment: @MikeAllen it doesn't matter. I added a comment to your answer that shows the problem without calling any unknown methods.
It does not matter what kind of implementation of `clone` it is using. The problem is not with the implementation. The problem is that _invoking_ clone is not allowed.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I'm agreeing with your conclusions. The default `clone()` uses some magic to create a copy of an object. Maybe the _Scala_ compiler is defending against that? Either way, I agree that you should be able to access the method as a public method through the interface.

Comment: @MikeAllen I do agree, that implementation looks broken. It doesn't copy `externalDoc` or `title` for example.It's probably a good thing that I am unable to use it :D 
But my question is not about swagger or any particular implementation.. It is about a generic issue of scala code not being able to access a public method via a java interface, which seems like a bug in the scala compiler to me.
The default `clone` isn't using any magic ... It's just a native `memcopy` implementation.

Comment: I'd be curious whether this is the case for _any_ method other than `clone()`, because of the magic associated with it.

Comment: Heh ... it's not easy to come up with another method example ... because interfaces cannot extend classes (other than Object), and cannot have protected methods ... So, I am thinking, `clone` is probably the only example like this :/

Comment: `finalize` is another method just like `clone`, and I was able to reproduce the compile error with `finalize`

Comment: Are you certain that this works in _Java_ code, and that it's not just _Scala_ that has a problem with it?

Comment: @MikeAllen yeah, I am certain.